# case on monadic value

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to perform a case on the value stored within a monad without having to bind a name to it?

i.e. instead of doing this:

```
c <- getChar
case c of
  ...
```

Is there a way to do this:

```
mcase getChar of
  ...
```

Alternatively, it would be nice if the case statement could be partially applied so:

```
case of
  ...
```

would be desugared to:

```
\a -> case a of
  ...
```

So you could do this:

```
getChar >>= case of
              ...
```

Comment: You might already be aware of this, but there was a [discussion](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/81366/) on haskell-cafe about this exact feature. The GHC side [doesn't seem to have a problem with it](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/81533), so maybe we will see this implemented sooner or later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. In Haskell 98, you can't use a case statement without using a name inside it. But there is a [proposal](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/LambdaCase) for adding support for case-lambdas. The syntax they propose is the same you propose too.

Answer (score 20):

The proposal mentioned by FUZxxl was now implemented in GHC since 7.6.1, it's called `LambdaCase`.

Now you can do:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
getChar >>= \case
   ...
```

Note the `\` before the `case` keyword and the fact that there is no `of` in that case.

Comment: There should be also something similiar for `if` :D

Comment: @remdezx, you don't really need something similar for `if`. Just use `bool` from `Data.Boolean`.

Answer (score 6):

No, not really, but you can move the case into another function and apply it to the result of a monadic action.

```
f x = case  x of ...

main = do
  f <$> getChar
```

Alternativly, the following is possible:

```
getChar >>= \x -> case x of ...
```

Comment: Yeah, but then the value **is** assigned the name `x`.  I run into this when I'm changing non-monadic code into monadic code and have to do surgery on case statements.

Comment: I think the first case is the best. Then you can drop the case statement all together and do the pattern matching in the function definition.