# Should I avoid using Monad fail?

Tags: monads, haskell

I'm fairly new to Haskell and have been slowly getting the idea that there's something wrong with the existence of Monad fail. Real World Haskell [warns against its use](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html#x_Et) ("Once again, we recommend that you almost always avoid using fail!"). I just noticed today that Ross Paterson called it "a wart, not a design pattern" [back in 2008](http://haskell.1045720.n5.nabble.com/Proposal-Add-Text-Read-maybeRead-Read-a-gt-String-gt-Maybe-a-td3174167.html) (and seemed to get quite some agreement in that thread).

While watching Dr Ralf Lämmel [talk on the essence of functional programming](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Ralf-Lmmel-AFP-The-Quick-Essence-of-Functional-Programming), I started to understand a possible tension which may have led to Monad fail. In the lecture, Ralf talks about adding various monadic effects to a base monadic parser (logging, state etc). Many of the effects required changes to the base parser and sometimes the data types used. I figured that the addition of 'fail' to all monads might have been a compromise because 'fail' is so common and you want to avoid changes to the 'base' parser (or whatever) as much as possible. Of course, some kind of 'fail' makes sense for parsers but not always, say, put/get of State or ask/local of Reader.

Let me know if I could be off onto the wrong track.

Should I avoid using Monad fail?
What are the alternatives to Monad fail?
Are there any alternative monad libraries that do not include this "design wart"?
Where can I read more about the history around this design decision?

Comment: [Real World Haskell says](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monads.html#monads.monad.fail) "[in many monads] `fail` uses `error`. Calling `error` is usually highly undesirable, since it throws an exception that callers either cannot catch or will not expect."

Comment: I believe "fail" is required to handle pattern match failures when you so stuff like:  "Just x <- somethingReturningIoMaybe".

Comment: @Paul Johnson why? The GHC runtime willl happily crash a regular function on a failed patter match. It is only required in the sense that monad instances have the power to catch that error, which is a hack not really exclusive to or ubiquitous of monads.

Comment: You should use [**`MonadFail`**](https://wiki.haskell.org/MonadFail_Proposal)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some monads have a sensible failure mechanism, e.g. the terminal monad:

```
data Fail x = Fail
```

Some monads don't have a sensible failure mechanism (`undefined` is not sensible), e.g. the initial monad:

```
data Return x = Return x
```

In that sense, it's clearly a wart to require all monads to have a `fail` method. If you're writing programs that abstract over monads `(Monad m) =>`, it's not very healthy to make use of that generic `m`'s `fail` method. That would result in a function you can instantiate with a monad where `fail` shouldn't really exist.

I see fewer objections to using `fail` (especially indirectly, by matching `Pat <- computation`) when working in a specific monad for which a good `fail` behaviour has been clearly specified. Such programs would hopefully survive a return to the old discipline where nontrivial pattern matching created a demand for `MonadZero` instead of just `Monad`.

One might argue that the better discipline is always to treat failure-cases explicitly. I object to this position on two counts: (1) that the point of monadic programming is to avoid such clutter, and (2) that the current notation for case analysis on the result of a monadic computation is so awful. The next release of SHE will support the notation (also found in other variants)

```
case <- computation of
  Pat_1 -> computation_1
  ...
  Pat_n -> computation_n
```

which might help a little.

But this whole situation is a sorry mess. It's often helpful to characterize monads by the operations which they support. You can see `fail`, `throw`, etc as operations supported by some monads but not others. Haskell makes it quite clumsy and expensive to support small localized changes in the set of operations available, introducing new operations by explaining how to handle them in terms of the old ones. If we seriously want to do a neater job here, we need to rethink how `catch` works, to make it a translator between *different* local error-handling mechanisms. I often want to bracket a computation which can fail uninformatively (e.g. by pattern match failure) with a handler that adds more contextual information before passing on the error. I can't help feeling that it's sometimes more difficult to do that than it should be.

So, this is a could-do-better issue, but at the very least, use `fail` only for specific monads which offer a sensible implementation, and handle the 'exceptions' properly.

Comment: Excuse me, what is that "SHE" that you mention?

Comment: It's the Strathclyde Haskell Enhancement, my preprocessor supporting experimental features (fake dependent types, mostly). But these days, SHE has been made redundant by the adoption of much of that functionality into GHC.

Comment: Seems like the proposed syntax was not adopted, but you can use a separate function or use LambdaCase (if you don't use do notation). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5395517/309483

Answer (score 27):

In Haskell 1.4 (1997) there was no `fail`.  Instead, there was a `MonadZero` type class which contained a `zero` method.  Now, the `do` notation used `zero` to indicate pattern match failure; this caused surprises to people: whether their function needed `Monad` or `MonadZero` depended on how they used the `do` notation in it.

When Haskell 98 was designed a bit later, they did several changes to make programming simpler to the novice.  For example, monad comprehensions were turned into list comprehensions.  Similarly, to remove the `do` type class issue, the `MonadZero` class was removed; for the use of `do`, the method `fail` was added to `Monad`; and for other uses of `zero`, a `mzero` method was added to `MonadPlus`.

There is, I think, a good argument to be made that `fail` should not be used for anything explicitly; its only intended use is in the translation of the `do` notation.  Nevertheless, I myself am often naughty and use `fail` explicitly, too.

You can access the original 1.4 and 98 reports [here](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Language_and_library_specification#Historic_development_of_Haskell).  I'm sure the discussion leading to the change can be found in some email list archives, but I don't have links handy.

Comment: "I myself am often naughty and use `fail` explicitly". Often? Explain.

Comment: @DanBurton: What is there to explain?  If I am in a monadic context, I tend to use `fail` to signal failure, unless I have a specific need to use another mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to hear about the history. I didn't know that Haskell originally only had do notation (without list comprehensions). I found an interesting thread in the mailing list archive http://www.mail-archive.com/haskell@haskell.org/msg03002.html

Comment: @StevenShaw, list comprehensions are older than do notation.  It's just that for a while, in Haskell, list comprehensions had been generalized into monad comprehensions.  They still worked for lists but also for all other monads.

Comment: "For example, monad comprehensions were turned into list comprehensions".  And then 10 years later, Scala got monad comprehension. :-/

Answer (score 10):

I try to avoid Monad fail wherever possible, and there are a whole variety of ways to capture fail depending on your circumstance. Edward Yang has written a good overview on his blog in the article titled [8 ways to report errors in Haskell revisited](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/).

In summary, the different ways to report errors that he identifies are:

1. Use error
2. Use Maybe a
3. Use Either String a
4. Use Monad and fail to generalize 1-3
5. Use MonadError and a custom error type
6. Use throw in the IO monad
7. Use ioError and catch
8. Go nuts with monad transformers
9. Checked exceptions
10. Failure

Of these, I would be tempted to use option 3, with `Either e b` if I know how to handle the error, but need a little more context.

Comment: Or `Maybe`... Using either one is nice. Its annoying using a library that uses Either and a library that uses Maybe in the same code, though. Monad transformers aren't quite as nice...

Answer (score 2):

If you use GHC 8.6.1 or above, there is a new class called `MonadFail` and a language extension called `MonadFailDesugaring`. If you have access to these, use them. You can then use `fail` without a problem that some monad actually has no fail implementation.

This extension makes the `fail` desugaring requires a more restrictive `MonadFail` instead of any monad.