# Trying to get rid of nested expressions

Tags: haskell

I have a yaml file:

```
base123:
  key1: "key1"
  key2: "key2"
  key3: "key3"
```

and code which is suppoused to read all 3 values from it:

```
read123 :: IO (String, String, String)
read123 = do
  rawConfig <- Y.decodeFile "config.yml" :: IO (Maybe Y.Value)
  case rawConfig of
    Just res1 ->
      case res1 of
        Object res2 ->
          case (LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2) of
            Just (Object res3) -> 
              case (LHashMap.lookup "key1" res3) of
                Just (String key1) -> 
                  case (LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3) of
                    Just (String key2) -> 
                      case (LHashMap.lookup "key3" res3) of
                        Just (String key3) -> return (key1, key2, key3)
        _ -> error "some error"        

    Nothing -> error "error123"
```

It seems to work fine. But I believe, there must a way to get rid of nested expressions without using Lens. Is there any? Or is there any way to do the same thing simpler?

**UPDATE**:

```
  rawConfig <- Y.decodeFile "config.yml" :: IO (Maybe Y.Value)
  case rawConfig of
    Just (Object res1) -> LHashMap.lookup "base123" res1
    Nothing -> error "error"

  return ("", "", "") -- stub
```

error:

```
Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO Value
      Actual type: Maybe Value
    In the return type of a call of `LHashMap.lookup'
```

Comment: If your code works, please consider asking your question on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This question seems totally appropriate for Stack Overflow to me—the request is very specific (getting rid of nested expressions), not just "help me improve my code".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use proper data type for storing your YAML data. Michael Snoyman's [yaml](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yaml) library reuses most of the API from `aeson`. So it is quite similar to how you work with aeson package. Here is a sample code which works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad (mzero)
import Data.Text
import Data.Yaml

data Base = Base {
  key1 :: Text,
  key2 :: Text,
  key3 :: Text
  } deriving (Show)

instance FromJSON Base where
  parseJSON (Object v) = Base <$>
                         ((v .: "base123") >>= (.: "key1")) <*>
                         ((v .: "base123") >>= (.: "key2")) <*>
                         ((v .: "base123") >>= (.: "key3"))

  parseJSON _ = mzero

main = do
  b <- decodeFile "/home/sibi/yaml.yml" :: IO (Maybe Base)
  print b
```

In ghci:

```
λ> main
Just (Base {key1 = "key1", key2 = "key2", key3 = "key3"})
```

Comment: I decided to go with your approach. One more thing: could you explain what the order of "evaluation" the expressions in `parseJSON (Object v) = Base <$> ...`, in particular, which function `<*>` is evaluated first: the first or second one?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Sorry, I cannot understand your question properly. The whole `Base <$> ....` is application of one function which results in the type of `Parser Base`. Let me know if that doesn't solve your doubt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982786/order-of-evaluation-for-multiple-operators-in-infix-form

Answer (score 5):

This could be simplified using the `Maybe` monad.

Let's focus on the snippet

```
case (LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2) of
  Just (Object res3) -> 
    case (LHashMap.lookup "key1" res3) of
      Just (String key1) -> 
        case (LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3) of
          Just (String key2) -> 
            case (LHashMap.lookup "key3" res3) of
              Just (String key3) -> return (key1, key2, key3)
```

First let's define extractors for `Object` and `String` (I don't know the exact types you need, but this should be obvious):

```
getString :: (MonadPlus m) => ... -> m String
getString (String o) = return o
getString _          = mzero

getObject :: ...
getObject (Object o) = return o
getObject _          = mzero
```

Now the snippet can be replaced by computations in the `Maybe` monad:

```
do -- in the Maybe moned
  res3 <- getObject =<< LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2
  key1 <- getString =<< LHashMap.lookup "key1" res3
  key2 <- getString =<< LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3
  key3 <- getString =<< LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3
  return (key1, key2, key3)
```

If everything succeeds, you'll get `Just (...)`, otherwise `Nothing` (which you can turn into an `IO` error).

---

Aside: notice that your nested `case` expressions won't work as intended, as they form incomplete patterns. For example if you define

```
test x y =
  case x of
    Just x' ->
      case y of
        Just y' -> True
    _ -> False
```

then `test (Just 0) Nothing` fails. The `_` pattern works only for the outer-most `case`, not for the inner ones.

Also I'd suggest to split the pure part (processing the data in a pure function) from the `IO` part.

Comment: but! since it reads a file then the return type must be IO of something, isn't that right? And since it's IO you can't use Maybe with "<-".

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp that is a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: You do not need `getObject` and `getString` functions.  You can just do `Object res3 <- LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2` etc.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, are you sure? I as expected, got the error `Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO Value
      Actual type: Maybe Value`

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Your update has nothing to do with what I said, which was in reference to PetrPudlák's code.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp However, I sense this has to do with not clearing up the "fundamental misunderstanding" mentioned above. Indeed you are *right* that you cannot use both `IO` and `Maybe` in the same `do` block. What you need is to ... let me make it into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The above discussion about how to use the `Maybe` monad for this got a bit too complicated for me to explain my ideas in comments, so here is how I might put it together (based on the original question, Petr Pudlák's `do` block, and my suggestion that `getString` and `getObject` weren't needed):

```
read123 = do -- this do block is in the IO Monad
  rawConfig <- Y.decodeFile "config.yml" :: IO (Maybe Y.Value)
  case
    do -- this do block is in the Maybe Monad
      Object res2 <- rawConfig
      Object res3 <- LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2
      String key1 <- LHashMap.lookup "key1" res3
      String key2 <- LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3
      String key3 <- LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3
      return (key1, key2, key3)
    of -- now we are matching on the result of the Maybe do block, to use in the outer IO block
      Just tup -> return tup
      Nothing  -> error "Some error"
```

Comment: I'd be worth adding that this relies on `Maybe`'s [`fail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:fail) function for failing pattern matching. In this case it's completely sensible. See also [Should I avoid using Monad fail?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8163852/1333025)

Comment: @PetrPudlák Many people think `fail` in this context should be replaced with `mzero` or something else not forced hackishly into the `Monad` class, but I don't think there are that many who argue that it's wrong for `Maybe`, `[]` and similar `Monad`s to support pattern matching in `do` at *all*.

Comment: Thanks. Due to curiosity, is there any to not use the second `do` and use only `>>=` or `>>` in your approach?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Technically yes, but not really; for pattern matches in `do` the official [desugared form](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) is something awfully nested like `let ok1 (Object res2) = let ok2 (Object res3) = ...; ok2 _ = fail "..." in LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2
 >>= ok2; ok1 _ = fail "..." in rawConfig >>= ok1`. And when the pattern can fail you cannot really simplify that much.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp Wait, I just realized that PetrPudlák's original use of `getString` and `getObject` *is* a way to get around that, because those functions essentially wrap up part of the necessary `ok` functions. So from his approach you *do* get a prettier desugaring: `rawConfig >>= getObject >>= \res2 -> LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2 >>= getObject >>= \res3 -> ...`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use what is called a [Pattern Guard](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pattern_guard) and write

```
read123 :: IO (String, String, String)
read123 = do
   rawConfig <- Y.decodeFile "config.yml" :: IO (Maybe Y.Value)
   return $ decode rawConfig
   where decode conf 
         | Just (Object res2) <- conf
         , Just (Object res4) <- LHasMap.lookup "base123" res4
         , Just (String ke1) <- LHashmap.Lookup "key1" res4 
         etc ...
         -> (key1, key2, key3)
```

Etc ...

You might be able to do that directly in the case statement instead of using a guard.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend Sibi's answer - making data types and your own instances is the most readable and maintainable solution.  I'll still present an alternative progression:

**Step 1: Presentation**

Be sure you post questions with compile-able code. This includes pragma and imports.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Foo where
import Data.Yaml as Y
import Data.HashMap.Lazy as LHashMap
import Data.Text

-- For Step 3
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Aeson.Lens
import Control.Lens
```

**Step 2: Monads are a programmers best friend**

Consider using the maybe monad, as others have suggested:

```
read123' :: IO (Text,Text,Text)
read123' =
 do rawConfig <- Y.decodeFile "foo.yml" :: IO (Maybe Y.Value)
    return $ maybe (error "error123") id $ myParse rawConfig
  where
  myParse :: Maybe Y.Value -> Maybe (Text,Text,Text)
  myParse rawConfig = do
    res1 <- rawConfig
    res2 <- maybe (error "someError") Just (objMaybe res1)
    res3 <- objMaybe =<< LHashMap.lookup "base123" res2
    key1 <- strMaybe =<< LHashMap.lookup "key1" res3
    key2 <- strMaybe =<< LHashMap.lookup "key2" res3
    key3 <- strMaybe =<< LHashMap.lookup "key3" res3
    return (key1,key2,key3)

-- Helpers make things more readable
objMaybe :: Y.Value -> Maybe (LHashMap.HashMap Text Y.Value)
objMaybe (Object x) = Just x
objMaybe _          = Nothing

strMaybe :: Y.Value -> Maybe Text
strMaybe (String x) = Just x
strMaybe _          = Nothing
```

**Step 3: Lens**

Consider using lens and decent variable names.  Lens makes accessing nested structures much easier.  Also see [the tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lens-aeson-traversals-prisms).

```
read123'' :: IO (Text,Text,Text)
read123'' = (fromMaybe (error "error123") . myParse) `fmap` Y.decodeFile "foo.yml"
  where
  myParse :: Maybe Y.Value -> Maybe (Text,Text,Text)
  myParse Nothing = error "someError"
  myParse (Just cfg) = do
    base <- cfg ^? ix "base123"
    key1 <- base ^? ix "key1" . _String
    key2 <- base ^? ix "key2" . _String
    key3 <- base ^? ix "key3" . _String
    return (key1,key2,key3)
```